# Error when running GUI Wallet on Ubuntu (core dumped)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ubuntu

When I'm trying to run monero-gui-v0.11.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, I'm getting the following errors.

After running start-gui.sh on the terminal:

```
app startd
*** Error in `./monero-wallet-gui': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb48770c0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

monero-wallet-cli.log:

```
*:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2018-03-18 17:15:16.423         b751b700    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)
2018-03-18 17:15:16.424         b751b700    INFO    msgwriter   src/common/scoped_message_writer.h:102  Logging to /home/mk0/Desktop/monero-gui-v0.11.1.0/monero-wallet-cli.log
2018-03-18 17:15:16.425         b751b700    ERROR   wallet.simplewallet src/simplewallet/simplewallet.cpp:904   Unexpected std::cin.eof() - Exited simple_wallet::ask_wallet_create_if_needed()
2018-03-18 17:15:16.425         b751b700    ERROR   wallet.simplewallet src/simplewallet/simplewallet.cpp:4981  Failed to initialize wallet
```

I tried installing libraries, rebooting the laptop, etc. What am I doing wrong, and how to finally get the wallet-gui working?

UPD. > How are you running monero-wallet-cli ? 
I have very similar issues with CLI. Also, my platform is Linux x32.

Comment: How are you running monero-wallet-cli ?

Comment: Reply instead of editing your first post, otherwise I don't see the notification that you replied :) Anyway, you can do this: run "ulimit -c unlimited", then "echo core | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/core_pattern" then run the wallet again till it crashes, then run "gdb monero-wallet-gui core*" (add the path to monero-wallet-gui if it's not in the current directory), then when gdb has loaded, run "bt". Then paste the result (you'll need to press enter a few times to get through all pages).

Answer (score 0):

Core Dump is usually something going wrong on the software side.

This question is old (2018), so if anyone is having this issue I recommend they [install the latest version of Monero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12150/how-to-install-monero-on-debian-linux) and try again.

If you're still having the issue, you're probably encountering a different issue and should [ask another question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)