# How to install Monero on Debian Linux?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux

Debian is one of the top server Linux OSes, and has many popular derivatives including Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Pop!_OS and others. What's the easiest way to install the Monero GUI on it?

Answer (score 3):

Whonix has added Monero to its APT repository (you can see that [here](https://github.com/Whonix/monero-gui)) so the process is now pretty straightforward:

Download and add the Whonix signing key:

```
wget https://www.whonix.org/patrick.asc
sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/whonix.gpg add ~/patrick.asc
```

Add Whonix's APT repository:

```
echo "deb https://deb.whonix.org bullseye main contrib non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/whonix.list
```

<sup>**Note**: This line previously said "buster" instead of "bullseye" - buster is the old release - see [Whonix 15 Deprecation](https://forums.whonix.org/t/whonix-15-end-of-security-support-and-deprecation-notice-all-users-should-move-to-whonix-16/12473) for details</sup>

Update your package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the Monero GUI:

```
sudo apt-get install monero-gui
```

Comment: The best answer on all internet that worked for me, 100000000 thanks Dr Bracket

Answer (score 2):

If you're on almost any Linux OS, Monero can be installed via Flatpak.

1. Follow the Flatpak Setup if you haven't already: [Flatpak.org/setup](https://flatpak.org/setup/)
2. Install the Monero GUI: [Flathub.org/apps/details/org.getmonero.Monero](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.getmonero.Monero)